# Loop through Pandas dataframe to set values based on 2 lists of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the following code that takes over an hour to run
I have been tasked to make it run faster.

This is a sample of the Pandas dataframe.  It is 750,000 rows.

```
    YEAR    MO  DAY HR  TEMP
0   1948    1   12  6   21.02
1   1948    1   12  7   39.02
1   1948    1   12  7   39.02
```

This is the existing code:

```
mintempf_list = [-25.6, -29.6, -16.8, 8.2, 24.3, 37.4, 42.8, 40.3, 26.2, 14.0, -12.8, -20.7]
maxtempf_list = [71.6, 80.6, 91.4, 97.9, 102.2, 107.8, 111.7, 106.9, 105.8, 95.7, 86.0, 75.2]
for row in range(derive_sfc_df.shape[0]):
    mo = derive_sfc_df.at[row, 'MO']
    temp = derive_sfc_df.at[row, 'TEMP']

    for mm in range(1, 13):
       if (mo == mm and (temp < mintempf_list[mm - 1] or temp > maxtempf_list[mm - 1] or np.isnan(temp))):
          derive_sfc_df.at[row, 'TEMP'] = np.nan
```

I have tried using numpy vectorize but I get errors with the index of the lists.
Is there any way of going through the 750,000 rows of the dataframe any faster?
I don't know how to use numpy.where or Sereis.isin for a pandas dataframe.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain your code please? And give an example of an iteration?

Comment: I'm trying Guru Stron's answer as we speak...
What the code does in it's current form is this:
The max and min temperature lists are built from a database query that finds the minimum and maximum temperatures for each month.
For a Quality Control check, this code loops through each of the 750,000 rows
to check if the 'TEMP' column value is below the minimum or above the maximum.
If it is, then it sets several columns to np.nan.  
It will do it, but yesterday it took 6 hours.  That is just for one location and we have thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your array data into another dataframe, merge, update column on condition and drop extra columns:

```py
temps_df = pd.DataFrame({'MO': range(1, len(mintempf_list) + 1),
                        'min': mintempf_list, 'max': maxtempf_list})

df = df.merge(temps_df, on='MO', how='left')
df.loc[~df['TEMP'].between(df['min'], df['max']), 'TEMP'] = np.NaN  
df = df.drop(['min', 'max'], axis=1)
```

Comment: It worked and only took a minute!  You're a genius!
I get this, but it is just a warning.
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  derive_sfc_df[~derive_sfc_df['TEMP'].between(derive_sfc_df['min'], derive_sfc_df['max'])]['TEMP'] = np.NaN

Comment: That did it.  No warnings what so ever.  THANK YOU!